# Question about properties of congruence

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Why can we divide the following expression by $2$?

$$24u \equiv -2 \pmod{17}$$
$$12u \equiv -1 \pmod{17}$$

Comment: Because $24 = 2\times12$ and $gcd(2,17)=1$ and 17 is a prime

Comment: right, thanks!....

Comment: To obtain $24u \equiv -2 \pmod{17}$, type 24u \equiv -2 \pmod{17} when you are in math mode.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}24u\equiv -2\pmod{17}&\iff 24u+2\equiv 0\pmod{17}\\&\iff 17\mid (24u+2)\\&\iff 17\mid 2(12u+1)\\&\iff 17\mid(12u+1)&\because\gcd(2,17)=1\\&\iff 12u+1\equiv0\pmod{17}\\&\iff 12u\equiv -1\pmod{17}\end{align}